# Scanf() no lee correctamente lo que se le da de entrada

Tags: c, switch, scanf

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual tiene como objetivo final tener una calculadora con las cuatro operaciones básicas, con una estructura del tipo swtich-case en función del número entero que se le meta como entrada, 1 para sumar, 2 para restar..., la cuestión es que depurando el código he encontrado que no estaba funcionando debido a que el scanf no está leyendo bien, ya que siempre devuelve un 1 en todo, y, por consecuente, siempre entra en el primer caso de nuestro switch-case

Os dejo por aquí el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int op;
float x,y;

int main (void)
{
   while(1)
   {
        printf("Insert a number for a operation 1{+},2{-},3{*},4{/}...\t");
        op=scanf("%i",&op);
        printf("Insert your x...\t");
        x=scanf("%f",&x);
        printf("Insert your y...\t");
        y=scanf("%f",&y);
        printf("Op es %i\t x es %f \t,y es %f,\n",op,x,y);
        
        switch(op){
            
            case 1:
                printf("He entrado en 1\n");
            break;
            
            case 2:
                printf("He entrado en 2\n");
            break;
            
            case 3:
                printf("He entrado en 3\n");

            break;
            
            case 4:
                printf("He entrado en 4\n");

            break;
            
            default:
                printf("He salido del case\n");
            break;
        }
   }
return 0;
}
```

Con la siguiente salida por consola:

[image: Salida por consola del código]

Como podéis apreciar en la salida de mi consola el scanf no está leyendo correctamente la entrada ni de los int ni de los float, no entiendo qué puede estar pasando, os pido que me echéis un cable.

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque `scanf` devuelve el número de coincidencias que encuentra en lo escaneado, por lo que op, x, y, serán igual al número de coincidencias que encuentren (en este caso 1). Prueba a quitar `op=`, `x=`, y `y=` antes de los `scanf`, y debería funcionar como esperas.

Comment: Más info en https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf